# how to check that Google Analytics Tracking Code is firing on an iPad

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, safari, ipad, firebug

I am used to using the Firebug extension "Omnibug" with Firefox to check that Google Analytics Tracking Code is firing on my website. This application works very well and has minimal overhead.

I am now testing the website on an iPad and would like to know if there is a way to check that the GATC is firing on the iPad **natively**? I have spoofed the iPad UA string on Firefox on the desktop and it appears to fire correctly, however i'd like to see it happening on the device itself (if at all possible).

I know that Firebug can be installed on an iPhone by means of a bookmarklet, however it is 1) quite buggy and not very user-friendly and 2) it doesn't support Omnibug.

How can I check that my GATC is firing on my iPad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a debugging tool like Charles to send requests made on iPad via proxy to the desktop software.  Here's a basic overview: http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/using-charles-from-an-iphone/

This allows for records to be saved and analysed later.  Another benefit is that actual and not emulated user page interactions can be monitored.

(This answer was provided to me by a Web Analytics guru, who clearly knows his stuff).

Answer (score 2):

If it's local development why not just add additional JS code at the beginning of your GATC script, like an `alert('GATC fired');` ?

Or: See this discussion [on monitoring HTTP traffic](https://serverfault.com/questions/84750/monitoring-http-traffic-using-tcpdump) on serverfault. Some of the mentioned tools are available on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: I'm at the testing phase and i'm more interested in checking that the data is being fired off to Google, rather than the code has been ran in execution order. A plugin for Safari or Chrome on the iPad would be great here, but I don't think it exists.

Comment: @crmpicco I looked up a maybe helpful discussion for you, see my updated answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just check the Google Analytics live view section on a desktop when your iPad is on each page, that would show you if you're collecting data.

Comment: Yes, that is possible to - however, the data provided is minimal and would not cover everything that I wish to test.

Answer (score 0):

Visit the website on your ipad and go on analytics, under the tab home go to real-time overview.